# How do I fix this : FAIL - Application already exists at path /second

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, tomcat7

I'm having a problem that I don't know how to fix it. This the first time I have this problem. I tried to change the path in context.xml but it works the first time and remake the same problem.

Here the error :

```
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\chafy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\firstapp\target\firstapp-1.0-SNAPCHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fchafy%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext5856041917942518665.xml&path=/secondapp
ECHEC - l'application existe déjà dans le chemin [/secondapp]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Deploying application with war file 'test.war' to context '/hello' to server 'http://localhost:8080/manager/'
> Application failed to deploy: FAIL - Unable to delete [D:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\hello]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
> FAIL - Application already exists at path /hello

Tomcat locks files or directory location. In most cases, this happens after the first successful deployment and subsequent ones will be blocked.

**Resolution**
This can be fixed by adding

> ```
> <Context antiResourceLocking="true">
> ```

to tomcat context. The **antiResourceLocking** is by default set to false. More details can be read at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: I tried to change the antiResourceLocking but it doesn't work yet. I still have the same error.

Comment: the same for me, adding antiResourceLocking="true" does not solve the issue. Any update?

Comment: I change the flag to `antiResourceLocking="true"`, I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

helped for me
`antiResourceLocking="true"`
`mvn cargo:redeploy`